# Установка valgrind на Mac OS

Tags: macos, valgrind, homebrew

Подозреваю, что проблема где-то в конфликте 64x разрядных компонентов и 32x разрядных, но особого опыта админить мак нету, разобраться не получается.

Делаю так:

```
brew install --HEAD valgrind
```

Получаю:

```
==> ./autogen.sh
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD --enable-only64bit --build=amd64-darwin
==> make
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
make[3]: *** [memcheck-amd64-darwin] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: http://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
```

Характеристики тачки:

```
uname -a
Darwin o2gys-MacBook-Air.local 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Система:

```
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 14.3.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: o2gy’s MacBook Air
      User Name: o2gy (o2gy)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
```

Comment: Видимо, разработчики поправили баг - сегодня той же командой valgrind уже установился, и даже заработал.

Comment: А зачем `--HEAD` там?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну это опция для *homebrew*, указывающая на что-то вроде "бери нестабильную версию, я разрешаю". Подробно (и кратко) об этом можно глянуть [тут](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md#unstable-versions-head-devel)

Comment: ага, понял. Я обычно просто последнюю стабильную ставлю, хватает.